# Can I use Xcode compiled armv7/armv7s .so library in BlackBerry 10?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, arm, blackberry-10

I have built a standard ObjectiveC++ dynamic library that I'd like to use in a BlackBerry 10 project I have in the QNX Momentics IDE.

I use libtool to extract my .so files for 2 valid Xcode architectures: armv7 and armv7s.

On adding these libraries to QNX Momentics, I get the following...

> Library is not compiled for the correct architecture: *path to my
>   file*

If anyone has guidance on why these are not correct, it would be much appreciated.

I'm assuming others have compiled with Xcode and imported their libraries to Momentics BlackBerry projects.

Both run on ARM architecture. Is it possible to do this?

Thank you!
Frosty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have never tried it, but pretty certain you can't.
I would expect that Xcode builds Mach-O binaries while QNX runs ELFs. There ought to be other significant differences, e.g. runtime libraries and platform ABIs (e.g. syscall numbers may be slightly different, etc)

Comment: I suspect there's the small matter of a missing Objective-C runtime and libraries to content with as well.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense to me. I am trying to use an existing library written in Objective C++, and wrapping my interfaces with C++ headers using an opaque pointer (PIMPL: [link](http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects))

BlackBerry itself documents it as possible: [link](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/dev/ios_porting/objccpp.html)
That said, I can understand that you say Mach-O would be different, so I don't see how one would compile without Xcode...?

Comment: You can compile Objective C with `clang` or `gcc` from terminal, make script, etc. Xcode is not required to build ObjectiveC. Note that any non-trivial ObjectiveC code is likely to use library not available on non-Apple platforms.